# How could I located Ticks on certain ridge/edge in cube box in Graphics3D/Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, ticks

When I Plot a Graphics3D with samething like

```
Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"X ",  "Y ", "Z "},
Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10],  Range[-10, 10], Range[-10, 10]}
```

how could I specialized which ridge the AxesLabel and Ticks should located? I know in 2D plot this could be done with FrameTicks. However, in 3D, there are 12 edges. For every X-ticks or Y-ticks, there are 4 edges where ticks could be labeled. For example, `Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True]` and `Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]` chose different edges for Y-label.

Mathematica automatically chose the certain edge, the problem is, how could I appoint a different one?

Comment: Because this changes dynamically when you rotate `Graphics3D[]`, I don't think this can be specified.

Comment: can't it be specified for a given view angle/polit? @Feyre

Comment: That was my immediate thought too, there's nothing in the documentation though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**

[`AxesEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html) does what you want.

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}]
```

[image]

The following shows more specifically how each of the edges are selected:

```
p1 = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, None, None}, ViewPoint -> Left,  PlotLabel -> "x {1,1}"];
p2 = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, 1}, None, None}, ViewPoint -> Left, PlotLabel -> "x {-1,1}"];
p3 = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, None, None}, ViewPoint -> Left, PlotLabel -> "x {-1,-1}"];
p4 = Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, None, None}, ViewPoint -> Left,  PlotLabel -> "x {1,-1}"];

GraphicsRow[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

---

You can use [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesOrigin.html) to specify which location the axes originate. This point and axes will stay fixed as you rotate the graph.

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, -1}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Partial solution as this limits the labelled axes to any three from the same origin.

Comment: @Feyre now it's a full solution