# Custom positioning of axes ticks in ContourPlot3d

Tags: plotting, ticks

I had a quick question regarding tick placement in 3D plots. Is there a way to change the positioning the placement of ticks in `ContourPlot3D`? For instance, I want to place the ticks inwards although on the opposite edges of the box (opposite to the "default" settings). I am using Mathematica 12.3

A MWE would be:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

which produces (sans the hand-drawn ellipses)

[image]

where the ticks are placed on the left and bottom edges ({y=0,z=0}, {x=0, z=1} and {x=0,y=0} edges). What if instead I want to place the axes ticks on edges given by ({y=0,z=0}, {x=1, z=0} and {x=1,y=1}), specifically the edges marked with the ellipses (one of them is the same as with the default options)?

Thanks

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, AxesEdge -> {Automatic, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}]`

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be answered [How could I located Ticks on certain ridge/edge in cube box in Graphics3D/Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120454/how-could-i-located-ticks-on-certain-ridge-edge-in-cube-box-in-graphics3d-plot3d)

The answer is to use `AxesEdge` option

Comment: Your answer would be more appropriate as a comment., I believe.